# How does Uniswap v3-core derive the look up table used in TickMath?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, defi, amm

### Background

In `TickMath.sol` of v3-core codebase, `getSqrtRatioAtTick(int24 tick)` implements `\sqrt{1.0001}^n` with binary fixed point arithmetics in Q128 and down casts to Q96.

With a lookup table of Q128 entries `\sqrt{1.0001^-1}^{0b1}`, `\sqrt{1.0001^-1}^{0b10}`, `...`, the input tick is split into several terms multiplied together. The negative exponent is chosen to avoid overflow and the reciprocal is taken in the end for positive inputs.

### My Question

I have trouble reproducing the exact constants of `\sqrt{1/1.0001}^n` defined in the contract. What I've tried is to precompute in IEEE-754 doubles and convert them back to Q128 in python, as in:

```py
>>> int(1/math.sqrt(1.0001) * 2**128)
340265354078545014477014422800776036352
>>> 0xfffcb933bd6fad37aa2d162d1a594001
340265354078544963557816517032075149313
```

As you can see the result deviates the hexadecimal value `0xfffcb933bd6fad37aa2d162d1a594001` provided in `TickMath.sol` for `n=1`. My guess is it's due to precision loss and there must be some numerical methods to derive those exact values.

Hope to get some guidances here. Thank you.

Comment: It's a good question, I'm not sure if anyone outside Uniswap knows exactly where the constants came from. There is a version of `getSqrtRatioAtTick` in the Panoptic repository that apparently has accurate value, in the comments: https://github.com/panoptic-labs/panoptic-v1-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Math.sol#L113

Comment: @kfx Thanks for the info!